# How to translate “end-to-end encryption”?

Tags: translation

How to translate [“end-to-end encryption”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_encryption) to Esperanto? This term is missing in [Komputeko](http://komputeko.net/). Can I translate this literally as “fin-al-fina ĉifrado”? Is that even an correct compound word? Or is there are more suitable or common way to translate this term?

Kiel oni traduku la anglan terminon [“end-to-end encryption”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_encryption) al Esperanto? Ĉi tiu termino mankas en [Komputeko](http://komputeko.net/). Ĉu mi povas traduki ĝin laŭvorte kiel “fin-al-fina ĉifrado”? Ĉu tio eĉ estas ĝusta kunmetaĵo? Aŭ ĉu estas pli taŭga aŭ ofta maniero por traduki ĉi tiun terminon?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Celante esti komprenata, mi ne laŭvortere tradukus la Anglan vorton. Se vi volas esprimi, ke la mesaĝo estas ĉifrita tutvoje de la komenco al la fino de trareta sendado, mi uzus "tutvoja ĉifrado" aŭ "tutvoje ĉifrita".

"fin(o)-al-fin(o)", (kiel "end-to-end") estas konfuziga. Se oni iras de la fino al la fino, kie estas la komenco? Ĉu estas komenco? Tiu teknika vorto estas komprenebla nur de teknikuloj, kiuj komprenas ke temas pri "endpoint" de reto, la lokoj kie informoj povas aliri aŭ eliri de reto. Oni verŝajne povas uzi "fino" por tio, sed laŭ mi "ekstremo" estas pli klara.

En Komputeko, vi povas trovi "finpunkto" kiel tradukon de "endpoint". Mi konsideras tiun tradukon malbona, ĉefe ĉar "finpunkto" jam estas uzata multege por io alia, kio ne temas pri reto. Ĝi estas uzata por la punkto de la lasta frazo de teksto, aŭ por la lasta etapo de projekto. Mi ne trovis sufiĉe da uzoj de "finpunkto" kiel "endpoint" por pensi ke Komputeko tie havas priskriban valoron pri uzado. Ajna pli klara vorto estus pli bona laŭ mi. Sed tio estas alia problemo, kaj tute eblas ne mencii ian tradukon de "endpoint".

Tial mi elektus "tutvoja ĉifrado", kie la vojo estas de unu "endpoint" al alia.

Comment: ĉu vi intencis skribi _laŭvortare_ anstataŭ _laŭvortere_?

Comment: @Vidamuzo Ne, temas pri la vorteroj "end", "to" kaj "end".

Comment: La simileco inter ambaŭ hezitigis min pri via intenco, eĉ malgraŭ la kunteksto. Dankon por via klarigo.

Comment: Mi suprenvotis vian proponon _tutvoja ĉifrado_ ĉar mi opinias ĝin bonega. Tamen oni rimarku, ke ĝi estas via eltrovaĵo kaj neniam estis uzita antaŭe. En konversacioj, mi jam aŭdis la analizajn esprimojn _ĉifrado de unu ekstremaĵo al la alia_ aŭ _de komenco ĝis fino ambaŭdirekte,_ kiuj estas tre longaj kaj povus esti uzataj kiel _klarigoj,_ sed ne kiel _terminoj._  Do bonvenon al via termin-propono!